# Setting up kobotoolbox on a DigitalOcean droplet running ubuntu 14.04 via docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a kobotoolbox instance on a digitalocean ubuntu server via docker as described in https://github.com/kobotoolbox/kobo-docker
but i am getting the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP9sH.png) 
 I followed instructions 1 through 6 and got stuck at 7. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

The question was posted long back but this might help someone other.

In case of server instance kobotoolbox uses the **https** protocol and in case of local instance it uses **http** protocol.

It seems that you want to create the sever instance. And you are using the server environment file and docker-compose server file from the kobo-docker application. To resolve the issue you will need to add the CA or self signed certificates - ssl.crt and ssl.key into the secrets folder and add this folder inside you kobo-docker. This will resolve the issue that you are facing.